# JavaScript php global variable increament

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript function, when I call that function it will return increment a value which is set in a PHP global variable,

js calling funcion is : `dData()`

Js function:

```
var dData = function() {
alert(<?php returnincreament($_SESSION['UnarJ']); ?>);
};
```

php function is

```
function returnincreament($a){
             $_SESSION['UnarJ']=$a+1;
        }
```

i want increament alert value should be 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc

JSCODE

```
var datas = {
  labels: ["12 AM","1 AM", "2 AM", "3 AM", "4 AM", "5 AM", "6 AM","7 AM", "8 AM", "9 AM", "10 AM", "11 AM"],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(78,156,181,.5)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(2,119,158,1)",
    data: [
    <?php
    $j=0;
    for($j=0;$j<12;$j++)
    {
        echo round($udData[$j]);
        if($j<12){
                echo ",";
        }
        $_SESSION['udbarJ']=$j;
    }

    ?>]
  }]
};
var returndata=0;
var nextcount=0;
var dData = function() {
     $.post( "includes/hourlyud.php", function( data ) {
         //var p=data;
         returndata=data;
     });
     return returndata;
};
var index = 11;
var currentampm="AM";
var ctxs = document.getElementById("cd").getContext("2d");
var barChartLine = new Chart(ctxs).Line(datas, {
  responsive: true,
  barValueSpacing: 5,
  bezierCurve: false
});
var ampm = function(amorpm,cstat) {
    if(amorpm===12 && cstat==="AM"){
        return "PM";
    }
    if(amorpm===12 && cstat==="PM"){
        return "AM";
    }
    if(amorpm>=1 && cstat==="AM"){
        return "AM";
    }
    else return "PM";
};
setInterval(function() {
  barChartLine.removeData();
  barChartLine.addData([dData()], index + ampm(index,currentampm));
  index++;
  if(index>12){
      if ((ampm(index,currentampm))==="AM"){
          currentampm="PM";
      }
      else
          currentampm="AM";
      index=1;
  }
}, 5500);
```

Comment: Does the `$_SESSION['UnarJ']` actually need to be updated, or you just want to increment it client side?

Comment: just want to increment

Comment: That didn't answer the question. Does the `SESSION` value need to increase or are you just incrementing client side?

Comment: basically i want is, i have php array variable which contain numeric value, so eg when i call  js function dData(index) then it will go to function var dData = function() {
return (value from php with index calculation)
};

Comment: somehow i need php variable value in js function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is server side, it executes before the page loads so:

```
<?php returnincreament($_SESSION['UnarJ']); ?>
```

is always going to be the value it was. View the source and you should see:

```
var dData = function() {
alert(1);
};
```

Now to get this to work you need AJAX which will send a request to a PHP script on your server and get the returned result. Using jquery this could be done with:

```
var dData = function() {
     $.post( "file.php", function( data ) {
         alert( data );
     });
}
```

Then in `file.php` you'd just need:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['UnarJ']= ++$_SESSION['UnarJ'];
echo $_SESSION['UnarJ'];
```

Assuming `$_SESSION['UnarJ']` is already set, if not add (after the `session_start();`):

```
if(empty($_SESSION['UnarJ'])) {
    $_SESSION['UnarJ'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: i want return data from here
var dData = function() {
     $.post( "file.php", function( data ) {
         return ( data );
     });
}
but it not working

Comment: yes it dose, but not return the value to function calling

Comment: i added a gloabal variable, var returndata=0, but its returning first value 0;

Comment: Well since the alert is correct the issue is with your implementation further down the code road. You didn't provide that code so it'd be hard to tell you what is happening.

Comment: @ShimulChowdhury The issue you were having has been solved. This is a separate JS variable scope issue, which would be a separate question. I could present you a hackish approach that would work but you should get an answer from a user proficient in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is server-side and javascript is client-side it wont work like this. You´d have to use AJAX in order to get this working.

Like calling ajax request to a php script -> adding +1 -> returning value to your alert.